# spring-boot kubernetes cannot access the controller endpoint deployed in GKE

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am trying to deploy spring-boot application in kubernetes using Google Kontainer engine(GKE=>version 1.7.8-gke.0).I have created the replication controller and service. The replication controller and service was created successfully. Please find the below output for reference,

**Describe service**

```
kubectl describe svc spring-boot-k8-service


Name:                     spring-boot-k8-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=spring-boot-k8
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.59.249.64
Port:                     <unset>  9085/TCP
TargetPort:               9085/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30726/TCP
Endpoints:                10.56.0.5:9085,10.56.1.3:9085,10.56.2.7:9085
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I have couple of issues here,

**Cluster Details**

```
$ gcloud container clusters list


NAME    ZONE            MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE  
NODE_VERSION  NUM_NODES  STATUS
spring  europe-west1-d  1.7.8-gke.0     XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  g1-small      
1.7.8-gke.0   3          RUNNING
```

When i hit the **https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx ** It is not popping the username/password dialog instead getting following error,

> ```
> User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/".: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""
> ```

The other issue is, Using which IP address i can access the service? the one in the describe response is the internal IP. I also tried with cluster master IP but no luck it is not working.

Inside the instance, I did a SSH and curl it was working fine,

```
curl -X GET -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" "http://localhost:32432/sayHello"
Hello.Welcome to our site!!!!
```

But don't know which IP i have to use to access the above endpoint externally.

Any help or pointers should will be appreciable.

Comment: _User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/".: "No policy matched.\nUnknown user \"system:anonymous\""_ is that coming from your app, or the request does not reach your app? I ask because your curl right below it does not use any auth, but you mentioned "username/password dialog" as if you were expecting one

Answer (score 0):

> The other issue is, Using which IP address i can access the service? the one in the describe response is the internal IP. I also tried with cluster master IP but no luck it is not working.

That part I can help you with, I think. The `type: NodePort` of your Service implies that it is listening *inside* the cluster on the IP address (and port) you see: 10.59.249.64:9085 but it is only accessible *outside* the cluster on the IP address of **every** Node on port 30726

If you wish it to be accessible to the Internet, you will need to create a load balancer, assign every Node to said load balancer, directing traffic to port 30726 of those Nodes. Or, as most people would do in that circumstance, use `type: LoadBalancer` to have GKE perform those exact steps for you, [as described in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)

---

Separately, if you are using the same `XX.XXX.XXX.XXX` from your `gcloud container cluster list` as in your `https://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX` then no wonder you are getting `system:anonymous` errors: that is the API URL of your Kubernetes master, which (with very, very few exceptions) does not accept unauthenticated requests. It is designed to respond to `kubectl` actions, very similar to how you created your `Service` and `ReplicationController` that you said in the beginning.